# adding HTML elements (not just replacing) with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div class = "chip chip1" id="chip100">#111</div>
<div class = "chip chip1" id="chip101">#111</div>
<div class = "chip chip1" id="chip102">#111</div>
<div class = "chip chip1" id="chip103">#111</div>
<div class = "chip chip1" id="chip104">#111</div>
<div class = "chip chip1" id="chip105">#111</div>
<div class = "chip chip1" id="chip106">#111</div>
<div class = "chip chip1" id="chip107">#111</div>
<div class = "chip chip1" id="chip108">#111</div>
<div class = "chip chip1" id="chip109">#111</div>
<div class = "chip chip1" id="chip110">#111</div>
<div class = "chip chip1" id="chip111">#111</div>
```

How can I generate this HTML code with javascript? I tried using document.getElementById("chip1").appendChild, but I'm not really sure how to use it properly. I was able to do it once with innerHTML but that only replaces it once and I want it many times each with it's own unique id. Thanks for any help!

Comment: for `appendChild` you need to create Elements, using document.createElement ... try [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) instead

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work:

```js
function attachDivs() {
  const container = document.querySelector('#container');
  const numOfDivs = 12;
  let currentChipId = 100;
  
  for (let i = 0; i <= numOfDivs; i++) {
    const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.classList.add('chip');
    newDiv.classList.add('chip1');
    newDiv.setAttribute('id', `chip${currentChipId.toString()}`);
    newDiv.textContent = '#111';
    container.appendChild(newDiv);
    currentChipId++;
  }
}

attachDivs();
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

To append to the DOM we need a container to [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) to.  We can create a loop that iterates and [`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)s the element we need, setting properties with [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) and [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent), then we append, increase anything we need to increase, and loop again.